# Утечка памяти и Bitmap

Tags: память, android, bitmap

Пишу сравнительно небольшое приложение. При его запуске размер `heap` 10 MB, `allocated` - 7-8 MB, но по мере работы с программой цифры набегают до 50-60 MB. При запуске `memory analizator` появляется сообщение

> One instance of "android.graphics.Bitmap" loaded by "" occupies 2,536,984 (21.22%) bytes. The memory is accumulated
>   in one instance of "byte[]" loaded by "".

`instanceof Bitmap` набегает до двухсот штук. Кто-нибудь знает, как это можно оптимизировать?

Comment: кто его знает. Может, Вы там загружаете картинки по 2 мегабайта. На первый взгляд кажется нереально, и загружаются картинки по 100кб, но нужно помнить, что они-то распаковываются в память. 1280 на 800 при 32-битном цвете - вот и почти 4 мегабайта. А если она будет просто зеленого цвета, то весить будет не много (пару десятков килобайт).

Comment: Да, знаем. Но нужно больше инфы, как вы их используете.

Comment: @bengal, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Проблема известная. При создании битмапа из файла надо создавать с помощью `BitmapFactory`. Попробуйте задать `BitmapFactory.Options.inPurgeable=true` - мне помогало. При задании этого флага битмап будет выгружаться из памяти.

Правда, в *KitKat* и *LolliPop* этот флаг объявлен *deprecated*, но там и машина типа другая, так что проблема должна быть решена.